# Find duplicate value in large amount of data

Tags: java, performance, sqlite, encryption, random

I must test an application that generate random keys. Keys are generated with the state of the system. There is 1,7668470647783843295832975007429e+72 states possible. The state change is pseudo random. How can I find the first duplicated value state of the system?

I have made some tries, but i'm far of the solution. Now I use sqlite to stock the data because I catch an out of memory exception if I try to do it with the system memory. With sqlite it's very slow.. I currently use Sqlite with only a text field (primary key) containing the state of the system.

I'm searching for an idea on how to find the first duplicated value generated by the system. Thanks you!

Comment: Perhaps adding an MCVE to show what you have done or tried would help a bit more. We can't guess nor should we have to guess as to your code.

Comment: With SQLite alone, pretty much all you can do is sorting the values. It might be a better idea to implement your own hash table or [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

Comment: @xXspynXx I think that the code is not really important here because I don't have a problem in my code. I just need an algorithms or something like that.

Comment: Not really a solution for finding dups, but if as part of your key you prefix with a timestamp then you really reduce the chance of collisions.Because now your set of values is only within a millisecond.

Comment: @RomainHippeau The goal was to build random key, if we prefix the key, it's not random anymore.

Comment: @rm4 It can simplify things in certain scenarios. It depends on what is important. Randomness or collisions.

Comment: @RomainHippeau in our case, we were analyzing the system. Our goal was to find at which frequency cycles happens. We could not modify the system to prefix timestamp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a big enough state space that I would guess you are unlikely to actually run into a duplicated value, but you almost certainly want to avoid having to actually store all of the intermediate values. I'd try something based on one of the two-pointer cycle detection algorithms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection